# How to get position of specific value in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((8, 8))
df.index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
df.columns = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
df[0][0] = "word"
```

Now I want to find the position of the string `"word"`,so something like `df.function[df == "word"]`. And I want the return to be `[0, 0]` for position

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `np.where`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((8, 8)))
df.index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
df.columns = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
df.iloc[0,0] = "word"
```

Find the position with:

```
i, c =np.where(df == "word")

print(df.iloc[i, c])
    1
1   word
```